# No permission granted even with intent filter and pop up (Android)

Tags: c++, qt, java-native-interface, android-manifest, libusb

So, I have an app that will interact with a USB device. According to the documentation:

[USB Host - Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

I created an intent in AndroidManifest.xml that looks like this:

```
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.qtproject.example" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="@string/app_name">
.
.
.
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
.
.
.
<meta-data android:resource="@xml/usb_filter" android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
```

My usb_filter.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="3341" product-id="5563" />
</resources>
```

When I plug in the device, the pop up "Open MyApp when this USB device is connected?", and I clicked OK. According to the documentation, this should have granted the app permission to do whatever it wants with the USB device. But when I tried to enumerate and connect to the device it returns the error "LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS: libusb requires write access to USB".

Note that my app is written in [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) using [libusb](https://github.com/libusb/libusb) if there is any relevance.

I have looked up other questions in Stack Exchange, but everyone seems to be able to access the device after they clicked 'yes' on the pop up, but not in my case, clicking 'yes' does not grant the permission.

Is there anything that I missed? I would like to avoid writing any Java code, because this app would be used across many platforms.